# Android: Can I listen for animation updates using TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition?

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm using the `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition` outlined [here](http://developer.android.com/training/transitions/transitions.html#NoScenes)
to animate two views swapping positions within a RelativeLayout. I do this by simply swapping the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` of two the two views.

My question is how do I monitor the animation that is automatically created and executed by `TransitionManager` without having to create my own custom Transitions. I need to detect when the animation has ended so that I can make a change to the views that have been swapped.

Below is the method that swaps the two views. CollageCanvasAperture is an extension of `View` and mApertureGroup is the RelativeLayout that holds these views.

```
private void shuffle(int fromApertureInd, int toApertureInd) {
    final CollageCanvasAperture fromV = (CollageCanvasAperture) mApertureGroup.getChildAt(fromApertureInd);
    final CollageCanvasAperture toV = (CollageCanvasAperture) mApertureGroup.getChildAt(toApertureInd);

    if (null == fromV || null == toV) {
        return;
    }

    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mApertureGroup);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams fromLP = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) fromV.getLayoutParams();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams toLP = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) toV.getLayoutParams();

    fromV.setLayoutParams(toLP);
    toV.setLayoutParams(fromLP);
}
```

I've done a few hours of searching on here and combing through the `TransitionManager` code but can't see how to detect changes. I'd prefer to be able to detect the animation end within the CollageCanvasAperture but can't see any relevant listeners to apply.

I guess I could provide the view with the destination LayoutParams before the animation is executed and then the view can listen for size & location changes until they match...?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

So it turned out it's quite straightforward to add a listener to these 'automatic' transitions.

Instead of using: `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mApertureGroup);`
you need to work out which automatic Transition is being using when you invoke `beginDelayedTransition` and call `TransitionManager.go()` instead.

My view transitions were using the [ChangeBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/ChangeBounds.html) Transition. Once that was know all I had to do was:

```
    ChangeBounds mySwapTransition = new ChangeBounds();
    mySwapTransition.addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) { }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) { }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {}

        @Override
        public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) { }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) { }
    });

    TransitionManager.go(new Scene(mApertureGroup), mySwapTransition);
```

Comment: You can also use `AutoTransition transition = new AutoTransition();` if you want to use default transitions eg. moving views

Comment: When transition is cancelled, the `onTransitionCancel` is called, and so is `onTransitionEnd`. But in what order?

Comment: Late addition, but it's also worth noting that there is `TransitionListenerAdapter` if you wish to only override one or two (or anything less than ALL) of the methods in the `Transition.TransitionListener` interface.

Comment: TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition() has second parameter - transition, so you don't have to use TransitionManager.go()